How to convert pydantic nested model to dictionary and push to dynamodb?
i have a pydantic model (sample below) in my python code. I'm reading the data and pushing into dynamodb. When I print each record, it has this structure:
{
   "Name": "jhon"
   "Address": {
      HouseNumber: '20'
      current: true
      street: 'easy street'
   }
}

but when I push the data to dynamo it is saved like this:
Name | Address
jhon | {"HouseNumber":{"S":"20"},"current": {"BOOL": true}..}

Additional keys S and BOOL are added for current and HouseNumber respectively.
Question: is it possible , to just save it as {"HouseNumber": "20", "current": true} ?
My code writing to dynamodb:
import boto3


dynamo_resource = boto3.Session().resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
person_table = dynamo_resource.Table('person')

with person.batch_writer() as batch:
    for i in list:
        #convert to json
        json_string = i.model_dump_json()

        record = json.loads(json_string)

        batch.put_item(record)

My models:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional


class Person(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Address: Optional[Address]


class Address(BaseModel):
   HouseNumber: int
   current: bool
   street: str


It is normal behaviour for DynamoDB. It automatically adds type indicators such S for strings, N for numbers and BOOL for booleans. This is how DynamoDB distinguishes between different types.
Only way to store data without them is to save an object as plain string.
with person_table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for i in list:
        record = i.dict()

        batch.put_item(json.dumps(record))

